# Google Analytics not showing new users

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm testing out Google Analytics in my app, so I'm running off the debug version of the app installed from Eclipse onto my phone. I can see my activity in the Real Time tab of the Analytics webpage, but I can't see any new users.

Is the new users data only available for apps installed from the Play Store (or signed with a release key)?

Comment: How long ago did you create the Google Analytics profile? it can take 24 -72 hours for it to start working

Comment: The profile for this particular app, or my user profile? The app profile I made just a couple of hours before testing. The user profile has been around for more than a year.

Comment: yeah wait until tomorrow for the app profile to kick in.  its normally 24 hours.  but Google says it can take up to 72.